# Bought a ticket with Finnair, didn't enter my middle name

Tags: air-travel, tickets, bookings, finnair

I'm travelling from Amsterdam, to Bangkok, via Helsinki. Bought a ticket with Finnair. I filled in the web form, and as it said "One first name is enough" (as also laid out [here](https://www.finnair.com/pl/AYPortal/wds/DisplayPage.action?COUNTRY_SITE=US&SITE=FINRFINR&LANGUAGE=GB&PAGE=ANCP)), I foolishly didn't fill in my middle name.

My first name and last name are correctly filled in. My passport has both my first name and my middle name under "Given names", which may cause confusion.

Is it OK? Seeing as I have a layover in Helsinki, it'd be even more stupid of me to be able to depart from Amsterdam, but not from Helsinki.

Can a name change occur?

Comment: No one cares about middle names in The Netherlands or Finland, but maybe it's important in Thailand where they are perhaps less experienced with "western" names. I don't think the answers so far cover that aspect.

Comment: My passport is the same way. It also includes my middle name under the given names. However, I've never used my middle name with an airline (unless they specifically ask for a middle initial) and I've also been to Thailand.

Comment: Even in Thailand it's fine. At the check-in desk they check (I assume) your passport number and then look up your last name and then see that everything is basically ok. There is unlikely to be a second person with the same nationality and passport number and last name on the same flight to generate any confusion.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [One Mile At a Time](http://onemileatatime.boardingarea.com/2015/09/06/middle-name-airline-ticket/) blog says:

> Even if you enter your first, middle, and last name when booking a ticket, the “surface” of the ticket (the e-ticket receipt, etc.) may not actually show that.
>
> Personally I often make reservations without putting my middle name on them, and I’ve never had an issue.

Comment: It's not quite correct. In many airlines in South East Asia you'll get problems if not putting the middle name. In that case you must call the airline to modify the name

Comment: @phuclv Which airlines? I ask because my experience it is not required. And I am also interested to know which airlines will allow a (non-trivial) name change.

Comment: @Calchas for example Vietnamese airlines like Vietjet and many other airlines who fly to Vietnam. In the west no one uses but it's very important in Vietnam to differentiate people

Answer (score 10):

In addition to other answers:

"One first name is enough" – this is the first bullet point in name change policy on Finnair site and *you already comply from the beginning*, so there is no need to worry. I understand that bullet point in way that even if name change needs to be done on air ticket, it is sufficient to keep only your first name and remove other given names during the change.

In my EU country (Slovakia), additional given names are "second class citizens" and are required only on security-related forms, but otherwise they are not requested, even not on tax forms, medical records etc. which are prescribed by law. Unlike the first given name, you can instantly add/change/remove additional given names in quick administrative process for about 3€ fee. Total limit is up to two such names.

Based on the above two paragraphs, it seems that also the Finnair views additional names practically and they are not really interested in them, unless you make serious spelling mistake there, which is a blocker. To minimize room for errors, they encourage their clients not to use them at all. These names do not necessarily appear on air tickets even if entered into their system. I would not worry about that.

Answer (score 9):

I used to have a middle name as a child (actually a second first name technically), and ***never*** put it in any reservations, even when going to the UK (which has strict advance passenger screening). ***Never*** any issues whatsoever.

Comment: Probably you haven't go to South East Asia? Many airlines there will put you into trouble if not putting the middle name.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Possible, like you said I haven't been there - as a child I never went outside of Europe

Comment: Just curious - you "used to have a middle name as a child". What happened to it? Did you lose it? Sell it? Give it away?

Comment: @Mawg Asked the tax authority to have it removed

Comment: @Crazydre Is it still on your passport?

Comment: @jwg No, not on my passport, not on my ID card, nothing. But you're missing my point: even when it was, ***no one*** bat an eyelid to me not putting it in any bookings

Comment: @Crazydre Ah, this may be a misunderstanding due to the present and past tense of 'put' being the same :)

Answer (score 6):

I had flown with Finnair inside Finland two months ago. I ***never*** use my middle name when I buy tickets, or even when I pay online (as the name appears on my credit card).

I never had any problems.

Answer (score 5):

Most countries have no such focus on middle names as the US, and a large amount of people in Europe have no middle names.
Therefore, Finnair will not even think about caring about your middle name.