# Middle Name missing on Cathay Pacific Ticket

Tags: air-travel, tickets, cathay-pacific

I recently booked a ticket through a travel agent which didn't ask for my middle name, and I've been told by a friend that I may run into problems because it doesn't exactly match the name on my passport.

In the [blog](https://onemileatatime.com/middle-name-airline-ticket/) mention in this [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/90097) it says that lacking a middle name on an airline ticket rarely causes any issues, however the first comment mentions that Cathay Pacific (CX) does require this.

I've emailed Cathay and they 'advise that the ticket should fully match the name in the passport', but I was wondering if anyone had run into any problems with Cathay and missing middle names?

I've also emailed the travel agent to see if they could change the ticket, but I don't know if they would charge for re-issuing the ticket.

Comment: if the answer for the same question was it is OK. I believe you will not have issue.

Comment: This question was specifically asking about Cathay, as the comment in the blog mentions 'CX seem to have a policy that requires the middle name in the name field of the PNR, not just in the secure flight info. Don’t know of any other airline that requires this to be so.' So I was hoping someone could elaborate further.

Comment: I traveled a lot, with different companies. I already had my name wrote in bizarre ways (like my two surnames wrote as one surname) and I never had any issue.

Comment: some info -> https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/cathay-pacific-marco-polo-club/1890512-missing-middle-name-ticket.html